# Cannot access my self-hosted website on port 80, redirected to router's setup

Tags: apache, web, port, web-hosting, self-hosting

Currently I am trying to host my own web-server. Unfortunately, I am running into a big issue with port forwarding. I have already routed the URL to my IP, and the web server is running on port 80. However, when trying to access my IP/website on port 80 (which is forwarded on my router) through any browser, the page that comes up is my router's web-based setup page. Apparently, its operating on port 80 as well, and I can't seem to find a way to get around it (when setting the Apache server to say, port 8080, the website works fine, but as there is no way to hard-code a different port into the URL, this really doesn't help). I'm definitely a newcomer to web-hosting, as this is my first attempt, so hopefully someone can point out a solution? The router model is a LuxulXen XWR-1750, if that provides any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup Port Forwarding on your router so that external access on port 80 will be forwarded to the ip address of the PC running Apache.

See [portforwarding.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm) for help on how to setup your router and what port forwarding means.

**Additional Suggestion**

If thats not the problem then you might check that the router is configured so it does not allow external Administration. If this is set to allow external administration maybe thats why you are getting sent to the admin config login screens rather than routed to the PC running Apache.

Comment: I already have port 80 forwarded on my static IP. The steps given on portforwarding.com just lead to my current setup. Trying to access the website just takes me to the routers set up page, no matter what device I use. It seems to me that for whatever reason Luxul is overriding port 80 no matter what has been forwarded over it. Any other ideas? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: See additional suggestion

Comment: Thanks Riggs! That seems to be the issue. I couldn't seem to find any documentation specific to my router (or Luxul routers in general), so I've emailed their Tech Support. I'll post back with answers if/when I get them for posterity's sake.